# Android SQLite DB in SD Card

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard

**SOLUTION**

### I had to override the getReadableDatabase() and getWritableDatabase() in my custom DBHelper class.

I am facing a unique kind of problem.

Until now, I have written Android apps that have used one SQLite DB internally on the phone memory, and it works perfectly. Now I wanted to add another DB and wanted to store it on the SD card. I did this by modifying the DatabaseHelper class that we usually use. I have also written a script that transfers the db from the assets folder to the SD card for one DB and the internal memory location for another.

Now the problem that I am facing is that when I try to access the external DB, android creates an internal DB in the /data/data/package_name/databases folder and thus I end up getting **no such table exception**.

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error!

---

**Edit 1**
My DB Helper Class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context myContext;
private String DB_PATH;
private String DB_NAME;
private boolean isExternal;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final String TAG = "ERROR";

public DBHelper(Context AppC, String DB_NAME, boolean isExternal,
        int DB_VERSION) {
    super(AppC, DB_NAME + ".sqlite", null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = AppC;
    this.isExternal = isExternal;
    this.DB_NAME = DB_NAME;
    setDbPath();
}

private void setDbPath() {
    if (this.isExternal) {
        try {
            DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/myappname/";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DB_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/myappname/";
        }
    } else {
        try {
            DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory()
                    + "/data/my.app.package/databases/";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DB_PATH = "data/data/my.app.package/databases/";
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (Exception E) {
            // MRC
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transferring byte streams.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    String filePath = DB_PATH + this.DB_NAME + ".sqlite";

    if (this.isExternal) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            File dir = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (dir.exists() || dir.mkdirs()) {
                transferFromAssets(this.DB_NAME + ".zip", filePath);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unable to create dir " + DB_PATH);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created
        // into the default system path of your application so we
        // will be able to overwrite that database with our
        // database.

        SQLiteDatabase db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db_Read.close();
        transferFromAssets(this.DB_NAME + ".zip", filePath);
    }
}

private void transferFromAssets(String from, String to) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream myInput = new ZipInputStream(myContext.getAssets().open(
            from));
    myInput.getNextEntry(); // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(to);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    AndroidUtil.copyStream(myInput, myOutput);
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + this.DB_NAME + ".sqlite");
    return dbFile.exists();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + this.DB_NAME + ".sqlite";
    Log.d(TAG, "Opening DB:" + myPath);
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

}
```

**My Internal Memory DB's class's constructor **

```
public WordsDB(Context AppC) {
    DBAPI = new DBHelper(AppC, "DB_NAME", false, 11);
    this.AppC = AppC;
    try {
        DBAPI.createDataBase();
        DBAPI.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        CustomToast.Toast(AppC, "", TCategory_E.CRITICAL_ERROR,
                TDuration_E.LONG, TPosition_E.CENTER);
        // MRC
    }
}
```

** My External DB class's constructor **

```
public BackupDB(Context AppC) {
    DBAPI = new DBHelper(AppC, "/mnt/sdcard/myapp/backup-db",
            true, 11);
    this.AppC = AppC;
    try {
        DBAPI.createDataBase();
        DBAPI.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        CustomToast.Toast(AppC, "", TCategory_E.CRITICAL_ERROR,
                TDuration_E.LONG, TPosition_E.CENTER);
        // MRC
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

The function in the external DB's helper class that leads to the error:

```
public void setValue(int No, int Stars) {
    try {
        ContentValues update = new ContentValues();
        update.put(COL_STARRED, Stars);
        String args[] = { No + "" };
        SQLDB = DBAPI.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLDB.acquireReference();
        SQLDB.update(TABLE_NAME, update, COL_ID + "=?", args);
        SQLDB.releaseReference();
        SQLDB.close();
    } catch (Exception E) {
        Log.d(TAG, E.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If I try to use the external DB as an internal DB, there is no error which leads me to think that there is something wrong that I am doing for an external DB.

Comment: Check the top answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806181/sqlite-database-on-sd-card?rq=1

Comment: post your logcat and db helper class

Comment: I have seen this answer, but I am still not able to figure out what it is that I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please provide some code?

> I did this by modifying the DatabaseHelper class that we usually use

Can you please describe what modification did you made?
If you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, be aware that DB path, that is passed to it's constructor - is relative to /data/data/package/databases/ folder, so you cannot pass SD path there. If you will still need this - I'll suggest using `ContextWrapper` and redefining it's `getDatabasePath` method to point to your SD DB.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I just edited my question. Can you have a look at it please?

Comment: Can you please provide where exactly your are getting "no such column"? I suspect that you are using getReadableDatabase() for this query, aren't you?

Comment: I used the same code with the external flag set to false and it works, well sometimes. I am confused!

Comment: Sorry, seems you'd still didn't provided the actual Query method which caused the error :)
Actually I believe that you do not need to extend SQLiteOpenHelper in your helper, it leads to a confusion. SQLiteOpenHelper  itself made to work with internal /databases/ folder, and even the fact that you initialize it with external path in constructor - means the  architecture mistake, I think.
So I suggest either to provide more code so we'll be able to figure out the current problem, or just rewrite the helper a little, so it will just return SqlDatabase from int/ext path, without SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Ha ha! I don't know what "actual Query method" there means, but this is the function that i call that leads to the error. And can you show me more about not using the SQLiteOpenHelper stuff..

Comment: Yes, here is what I'd expected. You are using  SQLDB = DBAPI.getWritableDatabase(); DBAPI, I expect, was constructed with "external" flag, right?
If so, there is a mistake. getWritableDatabase() is OpenHelper's method, which will use internal DB to open.
To quick-fix the issue, please try to override getReadableDatabase() and getWritebleDatabase() and return myDataBase in it. It should fix your problem for now