# read sqlite database from external storage

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, external

is there a way to read a sqlite database called "bai.db" located in external storage in a folder called "database". It has a table called "portions" and has a column called "questions" i want to get the question on id = 3 and display that. Is there a way?

Comment: See previous question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806181/sqlite-database-on-sd-card

Comment: @PeterIsberg actually i want to read not write sir