# Store sqlite database on sdcard android 4.4+

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i want  to store my  sqlite database directly on sdcard  in android 6 , so how can i do this ?

I created my DB with

```
public DatabaseHelper(final Context context) {
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + FILE_DIR
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

but it stored in the internal memory

Comment: And what is wrong with this code? Don't you have to copy the SQLite file into the app's data directory in order to use it, anyway?

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean , i want to store the sqlite file in the external sdcard  but with this code it was stored in the internal memory of the phone

Comment: Sugest to have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373863/how-to-store-sqlite-database-directly-on-sdcard
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806181/sqlite-database-on-sd-card
etc...
In fact, searching "sql lite on sd card" on Google give a lot of solutions.

Comment: i  tried a lot of solutions but it doesn't give me what i want and the file was stored in the internal memory

Comment: "internal memory" is an SD card (in most cases)... Not all devices have an "external" SD card, so I doubt you want this feature.

Comment: i want  to store the  sqllite file in the external sdcard (microsdcard) but it was stored in the internal sdcard