# use sqlite that exist in folder out of android project

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to build an application that use a sqlite db out of my project(suppose that the folder and database build by myself before and it is placed at "/Internal storage/myDB").
my question is how can access to that db (and "select * from tableName").

Answer (score 0):

In Android, I don't think you can create a folder with files in App's **Internal Storage** in advance.

See this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for Android Internal Storage

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user).

However, if you means internal (non-removable) storage kind of [External Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), then please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806509/267693) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373952/267693).